# Editing answers with low rep, a positive experience

Tags: discussion, edits, feedback

My apologies for not putting this in the form of a question, but I wanted to quickly share a positive experience I had with being allowed to edit an answer with low reputation.  I know that some are concerned about opening the floodgates for anyone to be able to edit content.

When I was looking [at a question on webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7135/1813), [one of the answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/adding-a-non-google-apps-account-to-a-google-apps-google-voice-account/7501#7501) contained a link to a Google spreadsheet formed that seemed a little shady to me because it asked for Google Voice security information and wasn't easily identifiable as an official Google form.

However, I found an official Google support page (via [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11996/is-there-a-way-to-merge-a-non-google-apps-google-voice-account-with-a-google-apps/12006#12006)) that links to the spreadsheet in question, which helps me to believe that the link is legitimate.

Under the old system, I wouldn't have been able to update [the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/adding-a-non-google-apps-account-to-a-google-apps-google-voice-account/7501#7501) with the link to the original site, but with the new system in place, I was able to make an edit that got added to a peer-review queue and hopefully this additional information will prove valuable to future visitors of this particular question.

Without being able to edit the answer, I would have resorted to simply leaving a comment, which of course could be missed by future visitors.  I found the change in being allowed to edit questions with low reputation to be a very positive experience.